# Show loading icon during server side functions on page refresh

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I have a flask app with some fairly heavy server side functions that cause a page to take a while to load. I'd like a loading icon for the few seconds that the user is waiting. Now the issue I am facing is that most of the solutions listed for this kind of thing are all related to waiting for the page *content* to load rather than the server side functions, so they just use an onload function and are home and dry.

I have a partial solution, but it feels quite hacky. Imagine I have **Page 1** which has a link in it to **Page 2**. When the link is clicked it fires off the flask function to retrieve **Page 2**, which is where the heavy lifting is done:

```
@app.route('/page2/')
def page_2:
    # do some heavy functions
    return render_template('page2.html')
```

Currently I have some javascript that causes a loading icon to show on **Page 1** when the link to **Page 2** is clicked, which basically does the job. However that doesn't work when **Page 2** is refreshed, or when it is accessed by another link in the webapp or its url directly. Ideally, I'd like to somehow navigate to **Page 2** and *then* wait for the functions to complete, so I can just always show the icon on **Page 2**.

How would I get the page to show a loading icon as it waits for sever side functions to be completed? Thanks.

Comment: I put the showIcon function call inside my ajax function, and the hideIcon function in the callback to the ajax request. I like this approach since it'll show the icon anytime I make a call, independant of the current app state.

Comment: Thanks Shilly, it was a variation of what you suggested that I eventually used - works great!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following implementation.

Have a loader `div` in all your pages.

`<div class='loader'></div>`

Apply default CSS as:

```
.loader {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom: 0;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
display: none
}
```

Have a `displayLoader()` function that changes the `display` property of `.loader` to `block`.

Have a hideLoader() function that changes the `display` property to `none`.

Now, suppose you are making an AJAX call, as soon as the call is fired or using `beforeSend`call `displayLoader()`, and the first line in the `success` of your AJAX call initiate a call to `hideLoader()`

Comment: I see what you're suggesting, but I've never used AJAX before. Do you think you could direct me to some material that would demonstrate the functionality you're describing?

Comment: There are several examples on the Internet. All of them follow a similar structure as the one I mention here in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/enqortjj/)